# Determinant of sum of kronecker products

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

**Question**:

Let $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$ be scalars and $V_1$, $V_2$, $V_3$ be $n \times n$ matrices. Further, the matrices can be expressed as

$$ V_1 = I_{d_2 d_3} \otimes W_1 $$
$$ V_2 = I_{d_3} \otimes W_2 \otimes I_{d_1} $$
$$ V_3 = W_3 \otimes I_{d_1 d_2} $$

where $W_i$ is a $d_i \times d_i$ matrix and $d_1 d_2 d_3 = n$. Then, what does the determinant of the following sum evaluate to?

$$ det(I_n - p_1 V_1 - p_2 V_2 - p_3 V_3) $$

**Some notes / results I found**

I know that there is the result

$$ det(\lambda I - A) = \prod^n_{i=1} (\lambda - \lambda_i) $$

where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of a matrix $A$. Hence, $ det(I-pA) = \prod^n_{i=1} (1-p\lambda_i) $. Hence, this problem can be reformulated to find the eigenvalues of the following sum

$$ p_1 V_1 + p_2 V_2 + p_3 V_3 $$

Also, the eigenvalue of a kronecker product is

$$ eig(A \otimes B) = \{ \lambda_i \omega_j : 1 \le i \le p, i \le j \le q \} $$

where $eig(A) = \{ \lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_p \}$ and $eig(B) = \{ \omega_1, \ldots, \omega_q \}$ for $p\times p$ and $q \times q$ square matrices $A$ and $B$, respectively.

Comment: As an easy case suppose the $W_i$ are diagonalised by $P_i$ ($i=1,2,3$). Then doesn't $P_3 \otimes P_2 \otimes P_1$ diagonalise every $V_i$ which gives what you want?

Comment: Great observation for a particular case, I agree, thank you for your thoughts. The relevant keyword here would be 'simultaneous diagonalization', I suppose, as also discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374836/eigenvalues-of-the-sum-of-two-matrices-one-diagonal-and-the-other-not). I had this in mind as well. Can one find a more general solution?

Comment: In general one first does the case where the elements of the $W_i$ are algebraically independent transcendentals over the field in question, in which case we can diagonalise, get result in terms of eigenvalues, re-express as a polynomial in the determinants and other invariant factors of the $W_i$. Then any particular case is got by substituting for the generic values. (Over $\mathbb{C}$ continuity arguments also work.)