# Eigenvalues of $A+v_1d^T$ where $Av_1 = \lambda_1 v_1$ (shift of first eigenvalue)

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have trouble to solve the following problem:

> Let $A\in \mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$, $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of $A$, and $A v_1=\lambda_1v_1$. Let $d\in \mathbf{R}^n$, then the eigenvalues of $A+v_1d^T$ are $\lambda_1+d^Tv_1, \lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n$. Note: $A$ may **not** be diagonalizable.

I know the following facts:

1. $v_1d^T$ is of rank $1$.
2. eigenvalues of $v_1d^T$ are $v_1^Td, 0,\ldots, 0$.

But I still have no idea to prove this theorem. Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1374836/499341 will be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch:** Use Jordan decomposition. WLOG, assume
\begin{align}
A = UJU^{-1}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
J = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda& 1 & 0 & \dots & \dots & 0\\
0 & \lambda & 1 & 0 & \dots & \vdots\\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \dots &\vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots& \ddots & 1 & \vdots\\
\vdots & \dots& \dots & 0 & \lambda & 1\\
0 & \dots & \dots & \dots & 0 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Since $Ue_1 = v_1$ then we see that
\begin{align}
A+v_1d^T =&\ U(J+U^{-1}v_1d^TU)U^{-1}\\
=&\ U(J+e_1(U^Td)^T)U^{-1}.
\end{align}
Note that
\begin{align}
e_1(U^Td)^T = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\vdots\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1^Td & * &\dots & *
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1^Td & * &\dots & *\\
0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \dots & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

Comment: But your assumption implies all eigenvalues are the same? then it may not be general.

Comment: Note the general decomposition consists of many blocks of the above form.