# Question about a proof of the Perron Frobenius Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transition-matrix, characteristic-polynomial

I am going through a proof of the Perron-Frobenius theorem that I found online, but I'm having trouble understanding some of the steps. Here is the relevant info:

Let $T$ be a primitive row-stochastic matrix. (By "primitive" we mean there exists an integer $k$ such that all entries of $T^k$ are strictly positive). I have been working through the proofs of the following statements:

1. $1$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.
2. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ then $|\lambda| \leq 1$. (And hence $\lambda_{\max} = 1$ is the largest eigenvalue.)
3. The algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda_{\max} = 1$ is one.

My current status:

1. This follows immediately from the fact that $T(1 \; 1 \; \cdots 1)^{\top} = (1 \; 1 \; \cdots 1)^{\top}$, since $T$ is row-stochastic.
2. It can be shown that $ |\lambda | \|\vec{x} \|_{1} = \|\lambda \vec{x} \|_{1} = \|T \vec{x} \|_{1} \leq \|x\|_{1}$. The last inequality is obtained by some basic algebra and the Triangle Inequality. The result follows.
3. This is where I am having difficulty. The proof I am reading through obtains the result using the following Lemma: "Let $T$ be a (square) matrix and let $\Lambda$ be a diagonal matrix of the same size with entries $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n$ along the diagonal. Expanding $\det(\Lambda - T)$ along the $i$-th row shows that
   $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda_i} \det(\Lambda - T) = \det(\Lambda_i - T_i),$$
   where the subscript $i$ means the matrix obtained by eliminating the $i$-th row and $i$-th column from each matrix." So far, this makes sense to me...The proof continues: "Setting $\lambda_i = \lambda$ and applying the Chain Rule from calculus, we get
   $$\frac{d}{d \lambda} \det(\lambda I - T) = \sum_i \det(\lambda I - T_{i}) \hspace{2cm} (*)$$

Each of the matrices $\lambda_{\max}I - T_i$ has strictly positive determinant by what we just proved. This shows that the derivative of the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is not zero at $\lambda_{\max}$, and therefore the algebraic multiplicity and hence the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda_{\max}$ is one."

I don't follow how (*) was obtained...How exactly is the Chain Rule being applied here? And where did the summation come from? And how can we say that $\det(\lambda_{\max}I-T_i) >0$ for all $i$? The author says this is by "what we just proved"...Where was that proved?

Probably I am making some very silly oversight, but any insights or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just think of $\Lambda$ as a function of one varibale $\lambda$ which takes $\lambda$ to the diagonal matrix with all diagonal entries $\lambda.$ Now $*$ is essentially coming from the fact (chain rule) that $\frac{d}{d\lambda}\det(\lambda I-T)=\sum_{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda_i}\det(\lambda I-T)\frac{\partial \lambda}{\lambda_i}.$

Comment: The fact $\det(\lambda_{max}I-T_i)>0$ does not follow from what you have written. But it is a consequence of the fact that all eigenvalues of $T_i$ are smaller than $\lambda_{max}.$ Once you know this fact, it follows that the eigenvalues of $\lambda_{max}I-T_i$ are all positive. Therefore, the determinant must be positive.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho Hmm. Let me see if I'm understanding what you're saying... So we are basically differentiating $\det(g(\lambda))$, where $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is defined by $g(\lambda) = \lambda I - T$, and where $\det: \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho Also, I have a few more questions regarding the argument for $\det(\lambda_{\max}I - T_i) > 0$: What is the effect of eliminating the i-th row and i-th column of the matrix T on the eigenvalues? Does this preserve the spectral radius? I came across this post which looks relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374836/eigenvalues-of-the-sum-of-two-matrices-one-diagonal-and-the-other-not .  Apparently the eigenvalues of $\lambda_{\max}I - T_i$ are $\lambda_{\max}-\lambda_1, \lambda_{\max}-\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_{\max}-\lambda_n,$ (so they are all positive).

Comment: @Leonidas Yes, exactly. We are differentiating $g(\lambda)$ using chain-rule.

Comment: Regarding your second question: Eigenvalues of $A_i:=\lambda_{max}I-T_i$ are not what you have written. Notice that $A_i$ is $n-1\times n-1$ matrix so it has at most $n-1$ eigenvalues, while you have written $n$ many. So, in general, it does not hold.

Comment: What you can rather use is the following. Notice that if $A<B$ then the spectral radius of $A$ is less than the spectral radius of $B.$ This is not hard to see. Now the idea is to look at $T_i$ and construct an $n\times n$ matrix, say $X,$ such that $X\leq T$ but the spectral radius of $X$ is equal to the spectral radius of $A_i.$

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho  Many thanks for the clarifications. The chain rule part now makes sense. And indeed, I made a mistake about the eigenvalues of $\lambda_{\max}I - T_i$. I still do not quite follow your last argument... So we construct a matrix $X \leq T$ such that $\sigma(X) = \sigma(A_i) = \sigma(\lambda_{\max}I - T_i)$ Now how do we show that $\sigma(T_i) < \lambda_{\max}$ for all $i$?

Comment: MSE is telling me to "please avoid extended discussions in comments." So I think I'm going to make a separate post to clarify this particular detail :)