# Given an $n\times n$ irreducible stochastic matrix $P$, how to prove that ${\rm rank}(I-P)=n-1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains, matrix-rank, stochastic-matrices

I want to prove that ${\rm rank}(I-P)=n-1$, and I know that $I-P$ is not full rank, all columns add to be $0$

I want to prove stationary distribution $\pi$ is unique by this so please don't prove it by $\pi$

Any comment will be appreciate!

Comment: Presumably, "irreducible" is pulling a lot of weight here, as the identity matrix itself is stochastic. What's your definition of irreducible?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this.  I walked through an analytic approach here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3788898/proving-that-deti-t-i-0-where-t-is-a-primitive-stochastic-matrix-and-t/ .  What that post implies is that the sum of $n-1\times n-1$ principal minors of $(I-P)$ is non-zero hence $\lambda_1$ is *simple* which is actually a little stronger than what you are trying to prove.   I encourage you to focus on the the special case where $P$ is a positive stochastic matrix as a lot of people get confused by irreducibility.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for comment, the "irreducible" means that all states of are communication

Comment: @user8675309 Thanks for your comment, but $P$ may not be positive stochastic matrix, and I think the solution is a little bit hard to me

Comment: A $P$ that is not nonnegative is not stochastic by definition.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. You mean the $P$ is nonnegative?

Comment: By definition a matrix $P$ is stochastic if it is nonnegative and its row sums equal one.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Sorry but the defnition isn't familar to me, and for example \begin{bmatrix}
  0& 1\\
 1 &0
\end{bmatrix} is also a stochastic matrix

Comment: Right! :) Anyway, according to Perron-Frobenius, if $P$ is nonnegative and irreducible, then it has a simple Perron root which would be $1$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron–Frobenius_theorem) ), and hence $I-P$ has a simple eigenvalue $0$, thus $\operatorname{rank}(I-P)=n-1$.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Thanks for your inspiration, I think there might be some relation between them