Algebraic Multiplicity in Perrons-Theorem.

This Segment shows that the Perron root in Perrons-Theorem(For Positive Matrices) is unique hence algebraic Multiplicity is 1, But I can't understand the proof and am confused because of:
(1) Difference between matrices Ai and A(i).
(2)Why the determinants of Minors is strictly positive?
If you have any other Intuitive or elegant proof, Please suggest it.
Note:Its not Perrons-Frobenius Theorem which deals about (Non negative matrices or Irreducible Matrices),Its Perrons original Theorem which only Deals about Strictly Positive Matrices .

It is Interesting Question

The matrix $A_{(i)}$ is the matrix $A$ with the $i$th row and $i$th column deleted. It appears that $A_i$ is the matrix $A$ with the $i$th row and $i$th column set to zero, but not removed

@Piyush For your second question, I suspect we're missing context. It says "by what we have just proved..."; I suspect that the thing that was just proved is not 5, but something from earlier in the section

I have checked the document its not proven,I think that result you are referring has come by showing that Det(rI-Ai) be positive then we can show that Det(rI-A(i)) is positive as it is equal to det(rI-Ai)/r.

I think since Ai is less than A,if we can just show that eigenvalues of Ai is less than Perron root than we can show above comment to be true

you can also show this by showing Adj (a-ri) is strictly negative, but I don't know how to prove this

you really haven't told us much anything about the matrices in question.  E.g. are they stochastic matrices; are they positive hence Perron Theory applies or are they non-negative hence the somewhat more involved Perron-Frobenius Theory applies.   In terms of pattern recognition I suspect you're trying to do the same thing as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3788898/proving-that-deti-t-i-0-where-t-is-a-primitive-stochastic-matrix-and-t/

They are positive matrices,I have mentioned it in question.

@PiyushChoudhury you need to tag people in the comments; the OP is always notified but others are not.  You said positive in the question but then said Perron-Frobenius theory not Perron theory which introduced ambiguity, especially since some people on this site use positive in a non-standard way .  Anyway I've voted to close due to missing context, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960 .  In this case what you already know from Perron theory is key.

Sorry for the lack of information,I have considered your response and modified to a certain what i think is right,i just want the solution to my ploblem.

I suppose that the proof comes from this handout. I have voted to close your question because it has already been answered in step 4 of the proof. (1) $A_i$ is the matrix obtained by replacing the $i$-th row and the $i$-th column of $A$ by zero. (2) By taking $B=A_i$ in step 4, we obtain $\rho_{A}>\rho_{A_i}$. In turn, both $\rho_A$ and $\det(\rho_AI-A_i)$ are positive. Since $\det(\rho_AI-A_i)=\rho_A\det(\rho_AI-A_{(i)})$, we see that $\det(\rho_AI-A_{(i)})$ must be positive too.
